Display the user role in WooCommerce admin new order email notification
With the following, I'm trying to display the user role to the admin new order email notification (code added to my theme's functions.php file):
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_user_role_to_admin_new_order_email', 10, 2 );
function add_user_role_to_admin_new_order_email( $order_details, $order ) {
    // Get the user role
    $user_role = $order->get_customer_role();

    // Add the user role to the order details
    $order_details .= '<p>User Role: ' . $user_role . '</p>';

    return $order_details;
}

But this has no effect. What I am doing wrong?
How to display the user role to WooCommerce admin new order email notification?
